# javascript math formula. find inverse

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, rotation

I have some function:

```
function calc_degree(a,b,c,cnt) {
    if(cnt==0) {
        return a;
    }
    b = b+c;
    a = a-b;
    return calc_degree(a,b,c,cnt-1);
}
```

Shortly, it calcs degree of rotation some cicle, which rotation speed increase smoothly. Function returns summary degrees of the rotation. For example:

```
calc_degree(0,0,1.5,6*1000/time_out);
//a - start angle; b-value of increasing ratoation degree every tick. 
//c-increase value; time_out - interval of rotation.
```

In this example, function returns summary degrees of rotation by 6 seconds.
So, how can I calc the "c" param, if I know the "a" and "cnt"? I need to get the increase value, knowing the summary degrees of rotation and time/tick. If my "a" value is 2790, I need to decrease it every time by "c" value and the last value of "a" must be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a proper recursion, with indices and all:

```
b[n] = b[n-1] + c => b[n] = b[0] + n*c

a[n] = a[n-1] - b[n] = a[n-1] - b[0] - n*c
```

results in

```
a[n] = a[0] - n*b[0] - n*(n+1)/2 * c
```

This shows you how to get `c` if `a[0]=b[0]=0`.

---

To get `a[n]=b[n]=0`, you would first need `c=-b[0]/n` and then `c=-a[n]/(n*(n-1)/2)`. This only works if in the beginning `2*a[0] == (n-1)*b[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your algorithm) I'll write function here, if it works)

Comment: Hm.. I've tried to realize it, but it doesn't work. 

    `var all_d = calc_degree(0,0,1.5,3*1000/50); //for 3 seconds the "a" = -2745; b = 90;`
 So, by your algoritm a have the "c" =  1.8970588235294117. 
But I need to reverse values for 6 seconds to values: a=0; b=0; and the c value is wrong. Where' my mistake?

For checking I've used `calc_degree(-2790,90,-1.897,6*1000/50);`

Comment: There was some small error, the new value of `b` is used in the update of `a` which shifts the sum over 0…n-1 to the sum over 1…n. Inversion formula added, note that there you need `b[0]=(n-1)/2*a[0]`, and then `c=-b[0]/n`.

Comment: Thanks! But it's not quite useful for me. Look, 
1) speed increase: `all = calc_degree(0,0,1.5,6*1000/time_out);`
2) then I want to change "all", for example all = all+59.5;
3) then I need to decrease "all" to zero smoothly.. 

`This only works if in the beginning 2*a[0] == (n-1)*b[0].` seems not exatly what I need.. of course, if I understood correctly =)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so I'll add it here. LutzL answer is correct. The problem is that if you add more than one constraint to the problem (in your case requiring both a and b to go to 0) you are reducing the degrees of freedom of the problem. In your case you cannot make a go to zero smoothly (with both a and b 0) if there's not the relation stated by LutzL in the beginning. You can solve it by adding another degree of smoothness (ex: c[n] = c[n-1] + d.) But then you wont be able to make a, b and c tend to 0 without extra constraints.